# Is there a way in Base R to replicate what VLOOKUP TRUE in Excel does?

Tags: r, interpolation, vlookup

I have a consumption pattern that looks like this:

```
x <-0:10
y<-c(0, 0.05, 0.28, 0.45, 0.78, 0.86, 0.90, 0.92, 0.95, 0.98, 1.00)
```

X is in years, and Y is not always monotonically-increasing, although it should be most of the time.

If I needed to estimate how many years would elapse before 80% is consumed, in Excel, I would use the VLOOKUP TRUE function which would return 78%, then I would lookup the next value in the series (86%) and then linearly interpolate to get 4.25 years. It's laborious but it gets the job done.

Is there an easy way to compute this in R, in a user-defined function that I can apply to many cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- 0:10
y <- c(0, 0.05, 0.28, 0.45, 0.78, 0.86, 0.90, 0.92, 0.95, 0.98, 1.00)


estimate_years <- function(x, y, percent) {
  idx <- max(which(y < percent))
  (percent - y[idx]) / (y[idx+1] - y[idx]) * (x[idx+1] - x[idx]) + x[idx]
}

estimate_years(x, y, 0.80) ## 4.25
```

Although the `approx` calculation is cool,
exact linear interpolation here is easy.
`idx` is the next smaller position for `y` and `x`.
`idx+1` thus is the next equal/bigger position for `y` and `x` in relation to `percentage`.

Through triangular calculation, where
`k = part / total`
which is
`(percent - y[idx]) / (y[idx+1] - y[idx])`

and applying `k * total_x`
represented here by `k * (x[idx+1] - x[idx])` - the result of the linear interpolation
and adding last smaller years
`x[idx]`, we obtain the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `approx`

```
resolution <- 1000
fn <- approx(x, y, n=resolution)
min(fn$x[fn$y > 0.8])
[1] 4.254254
```

The better you need your estimate to be, use a higher number for `resolution`

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for something exact (of course - whether linear interpolation itself can be considered an exact solution is another matter altogether!). having said that, learnt about resolution from your response which i previously hadn't been aware of!